# Как лучше всего реализовать LSTM модель многомерного ряда?

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Для одной крупной компании требуется написать нейронную сеть предсказывающая сколько товаров купит определенный дистрибьютор. Каждый месяц дистрибьютор присылает данные: сколько товара осталось на складе, сколько продал в течении месяца, средняя цена за товар и тд.

Дистрибьюторов работающих по такой схеме в районе 100 для каждого из них требуется написать предсказывающую спрос в будущем по каждой группе товаров. Можно ли с помощью одной нейросети LSTM сразу обучить на всех 100 дистр. предсказывать будущий спрос для одной группы товаров, если да то как?  Или же лучше для каждого отдельно учить нейросеть и сохранять веса? 
В интернете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чудес не бывает. Даже в машинном обучении. Либо вы строите одну общую модель, используя все имеющиеся данные и она выдает вам результаты ее для всех ваших дистрибъюторов. Либо для каждого дистрибъютора используете свой обучающий набор и строите отдельные модели.

Единственное исключение, если вы можете предположить, что результаты дистрибъюторов как-то зависят, например, от того -  в большом-маленьком городе он расположен, какая его форма собственности, количества сотрудников или еще от чего-то такого. Тогда такие параметры можно тоже использовать в качестве входа и строить единую модель. Хотя не уверен, что точность предсказания при этом повысится.

Впрочем, ничего страшного нет и в множественности моделей. Знаю случай, когда в подобной ситуации для каждого объекта предсказания строили по пять моделей разных классов а потом выбирали лучшую из них. Потом для каждого объекта мало того, что была собственная модель, так еще и разных классов.

Comment: Спасибо, а вот ретейлеры они сейчас тоже активно используют нейросети для предсказания спроса по каждому товару(группе товаров) в каждом конкретном магазине как тут работают временные ряды?) Это же сума сойти для каждого магазина строить множество моделей...

Comment: Если вы вручную собрались строить модели -  то да. Можно и сойти. Но профессионалы обычно умеют это делать программно. Тогда построение модели - это набор фиксированных шагов -  от очистки данных до валидации модели, которые выполняются более-менее автоматизировано. Только успевай данные готовить.